# Removing a dialog after a set amount of time

Tags: android, dialog, handler

```
public void isWaitingResponse (boolean isWaiting) {

    if (isWaiting && dialogLock == null) {

        dialogLock = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
        dialogLock.setCancelable(false);
        dialogLock.show();

        // ToDo: If this dialog is still showing after 10 seconds
        // Call the primary method within and activate the "else"
        // condition code below to remove dialog, and clear app
        // state for further communication

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isWaiting && dialogLock != null) {
                    // Recursively call this method as false
                    isWaitingResponse(false);
                }
            }
        }, 5000);

    } else if (!isWaiting) {

        if (dialogLock != null) {

            dialogLock.dismiss();
            dialogLock = null;

        }

    }

}
```

As noted in the comments in the code above, this does work and does what I need it to correctly.  I'm just wondering if I am leaving the handler attached or if **any additional cleanup is needed** to ensure no garbage is left behind in active code.  Not super familiar with handlers.

**UPDATE:**
I would like to ensure that this handler does not fire if the dialog was closed (this method was entered with a false parameter).  Therefore on false check, if a handler had a post delayed, that handler should be dismissed along with the dialog.  I must make sure that a later request is not dismissed by the post delayed timeout of a previous one.

**SOLVED, ANSWER POSTED BY MYSELF BELOW** - Thanks to Yessine.

Comment: Are you trying to run a `Dialog` for a specific time?

Comment: Keep in mind that the dialog will close if you rotate your device.

Comment: @superman: I just need to make sure the dialog doesn't stay there forever.  A 5 or 10 second limit would be fine.

Comment: @rekire the application is non rotateable, i.e. no config changes will happen and therefore no state changes need to occur.  Please note updated question, more info has been provided.

Comment: Turning the screen off and on is also a configuration change as far I remember.

Comment: @rekire then the user must log on again and all the checks are redone from the beginning, a progressbar along with a dialog lock would be placed up once again if relevant, even though user would be rerouted back to the main screen in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is an implementation of @Yessine Mahdouani's suggestion.

First off a Timer is created:

```
final Timer timerUnlock = new Timer();
```

When locking the process involves also scheduling a timer event which relaunches the root method itself:

```
if (isWaiting &&
        lockDialog == null)
{
    lockDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
    lockDialog.setCancelable(false);
    lockDialog.show();

    timerUnlock.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Close it automatically if running.
            m_setisWaiting(false);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

When unlocking ensure any timers are cancelled, this prevents a previous lock timer from unlocking a more recent lock that's not finished and neither timed out yet:

```
else if (!isWaiting)
{
    if (lockDialog != null) {
        lockDialog.dismiss();
        lockDialog = null;
    }

    timerUnlock.cancel();
}
```

And finally the code that will operate on an interface level should be run on the main thread (it was causing continuous crashes otherwise - possibly because the timer was finishing and triggering from a separate thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Remove any timeouts still running.
        if(progressBar != null) {
            if(isWaiting)
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```

Full method would be as such:

```
public void m_setisWaiting (boolean isWaiting) {

    final Timer timerUnlock = new Timer();

    if (isWaiting &&
            lockDialog == null)
    {
        lockDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Panel);
        lockDialog.setCancelable(false);
        lockDialog.show();

        timerUnlock.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Close it automatically if running.
                m_setisWaiting(false);
            }
        }, 10000);
    }

    else if (!isWaiting)
    {
        if (lockDialog != null) {
            lockDialog.dismiss();
            lockDialog = null;
        }

        timerUnlock.cancel();
    }

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Remove any timeouts still running.
            if(progressBar != null) {
                if(isWaiting)
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After showing the dialog put this code, it will run after 10 seconds

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
     public void run() {
     dialogLock.dismiss();
      }}, 10000);//time in milliseconds
```

Comment: How would I ensure this schedule is not run if the dialog was dismissed manually?  And "it doesn't matter then" would not be valid since a new separate entity might request a new dialog back up, which could be confused with the previous one.

Comment: you can test if the dialog is showing:  if(dialogLock.isShowing()){ // }

Comment: I think the solution would be based on what you described but reference the timer in a Timer variable and then call timer.cancel() on it if the section was cancelled manually, stopping any timers from further attempting to re-dismiss the dialog.

Comment: I don't think this works completely, been getting some errors due to running ui code from the wrong thread.  I should encapsulate some of this in ui thread but not sure which

Comment: Solved, added as a separate answer.